# Loading a model saved in s3 to SageMaker instance

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, aws, sagemaker

I trained a ML model in SageMaker using Docker Container. After the training is finished, the model is saved as .pkl file which gets written to S3 bucket as .tar file.
I need to use that model to run some inference, and with SageMaker Batch Transform is having issue with connecting nginx.
Is there a way, I can read that trained model and extract from the pickle file and to use as traditional pythonic way to making prediction on test dataset within the SageMaker instance?

Thank you

Comment: Which model are you using ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which model I am using. I have a custom docker container to run the training, and this time I have logistic regression. I found the way to unpack the pickle file using some linux command.
The reason, I needed to do this is to check file structure, so that i can update my opt/ml directory when invoking containers. 
Not having linux background makes it clueless.
I ran following in the notebook:

`step 1:  !aws s3 cp <s3 bucket folder containing model>model.tar.gz`

`step 2: !tar -xvf model.tar.gz`

Thanks